# How to prevent img src invalid and if it's invalid preserve previous image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am trying to stream live image to my webpage. When the image content is being  updated at backend, sometimes the path may return invalid content. How do I detect the URL contains invalid content, and thus do not refresh my image ?

My current implementation of image update:

```
function update(){

 $("#live").prop("src", "/HTTPGetImage?ImageIndex=0?"+ +new Date());

 setTimeout(update, 3000);

}
```

I've tried to use `.get()` to check if return data is valid.

```
$.get('/HTTPGetImage?ImageIndex=0?').done(function(data)
{
  if(data!="")
   $("#live").prop("src", "/HTTPGetImage?ImageIndex=0?"+ +new Date());
})
```

But this approach doesn't work. I think the updating is very frequent at backend, so between my first and second request to server, image at back-end might already been updated.  What should I do to avoid getting invalid content, and if I get invalid content, how do I preserve current img src  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pseudo image with jquery that you will not attach to DOM, and hook into it's `load` and `error` events. My example shows how this can be achieved - just implement your logic into onerror and onload handlers - if it loads, you can set your image, if error is triggered, show previous.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var last_image = 0
  var sample_images = ["https://via.placeholder.com/100",
                       "https://via.placeholder.com/101/000/fff",
                       "https://via.placeholder.com/error",
                       "https://via.placeholder.com/103/880000/fff"]
   
  function loadImage(){
      
     var next_image = (last_image == sample_images.length-1)?0:last_image+1
     setTimeout(function(){
         
        var pseudoImg = $("<img>");
        pseudoImg.attr("src",sample_images[next_image])
        pseudoImg.on("load",function(){
          $("#img").attr("src",sample_images[next_image])
          $("#url").html(sample_images[next_image])
          last_image=next_image
          loadImage()
        });
        pseudoImg.on("error",function(){
          // not changing previous image
          $("#url").html("ERROR LOADING "+sample_images[next_image]+"<br> displaying previous: "+sample_images[last_image])
          last_image=next_image
          loadImage()
        })
     
        
     },2000)
  }
  
  loadImage()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" id="img">
<div id="url">https://via.placeholder.com/100</div>
```

For your example the code would be something like this:

```
function update(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     var timestamp = new Date()
     var url = "/HTTPGetImage?ImageIndex=0?"+timestamp
     var pseudoImg = $("<img>");
     pseudoImg.attr("src",url)
     pseudoImg.on("load",function(){
       $("#live").attr("src",url)
       update()
     });
     pseudoImg.on("error",function(){
       // don't do nothing, just call next update 
       update()
     }) 
  },3000);
}
```

Comment: Mike, using pseudo image will make my streaming seems flashing between correct image and pseudo image, and it's not preferred..

Comment: You should not be attaching the pseudoImage to DOM at all, if it's not in view it can't be flashing.. If pseudo fails to load, basicaly you don't do nothing with your original image, thus it will still be showing the previous image without flashing..

Comment: i updated my answer with an example how your update() method should look like, just call it first time on document.ready